# PHP Multidimensional Array Empty Values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, advanced-custom-fields

I'm attempting to use an ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) table of data with a header row, and create a JSON object array where each object is labeled as the header value with the columns as an array for that value... My results are empty and I'm not sure why.

```
function get_rates_table(){
    $table = get_field('rates_table', 'options');
    $head = [];
    $rows = [];
    $each = [];
    if($table){

        if($table['header']){
            foreach ($table['header'] as $h) {
                array_push($head, $h['c']);
            }
        }

        if ($table['body']) {
            foreach ($table['body'] as $tr) {
                foreach ($tr as $td) {
                    $each[] = $td['c'];
                }
            $rows[] = $each;
            unset($each);
            }
        }

        foreach ($head as $key => $value) {
            $value = [];
            foreach($rows as $k => $v){
                foreach ($v as $x => $y) {
                    if($x == $key){
                        array_push($value, $y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $head;
}
```

The output looks like:

```
"rates_table": [
    "Term",
    "Rate Loan",
    "Rate Refi"
],
```

The original ACF array looks like:

```
Array(
[header] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [c] => Term
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [c] => Rate Loan
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [c] => Rate Refi
            )

    )

[body] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [c] => 12
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [c] => 3
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [c] => 3.5
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [c] => 24
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [c] => 3.1
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [c] => 3.8
                    )

            )    etc...
```

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I'm hoping an array like:
` term => [12, 24, 36, 48] , rate loan => [3, 3.5, 3.8, 4] , rate refi => [3.5, 3.8, etc.] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lot of code that I'm not willing to troubleshoot, but for one, it looks like you are only returning `$head` which doesn't contain any of the other values.  To make it simple:

```
$header = array_column($array['header'], 'c');

foreach($array['body'] as $values) {
    $result[] = array_combine($header, array_column($values, 'c'));
}
```

- Extract the headers from the array
- Loop the body and extract the values
- Combine the headers as the keys and the values as values

Which will yield something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Term] => 12
            [Rate loan] => 3
            [Rate refi] => 3.5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Term] => 24
            [Rate loan] => 3.1
            [Rate refi] => 3.8
        )

)
```

Using the same headers you can construct the array differently:

```
foreach($header as $k => $h) {
    $result[$h] = array_column(array_column($array['body'], $k), 'c');
}
```

- Loop the headers exposing the numeric key
- Use the header values as the key and extract the values using the header key

Which will yield something like:

```
Array
(
    [Term] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 24
        )

    [Rate loan] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 3.1
        )

    [Rate refi] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3.5
            [1] => 3.8
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's working well. I'm wondering though if it could be done to simply have a single `[Term] => [12, 24], etc. ` ?

Comment: Honestly, I think your original might be easier to work with, thank you very much for your help, and introducing me to array_column()